# VS Code problem when using magic commands in Jupyter notebooks: "Expected expression Pylance"

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

I'm playing around with Python's and NumPy's methods to compare their performance:

```py
import numpy as np

massive_array = np.random.random(100000)

%timeit sum(massive_array) # Python's sum()
%timeit np.sum(massive_array) # NumPy's np.sum()
```

Which works fine and returns the following:

```
9.56 ms ± 523 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
51.9 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The only problem is that, while using the notebook on vscode, I get an error flagged by `Pylance` regarding the percentage symbol for `%timeit`:

[image]

What's the reason for it to be flagged? Shouldn't that be a valid expression, given that it also executed successfully?

Comment: That's not valid Python syntax. That's an IPython line magic. This raises the question, why do you have Pylance checking for valid Python syntax in a Jupyter notebook that accepts input that isn't valid Python syntax?

Comment: Great point! After your comment I tested without the extension, but intellisense seems to be quite degraded; Do you perhaps know if it's possible to disable the warnings while keeping Pylance intellisense?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through some GitHub issue tickes, if I understand correctly, this shouldn't be an issue anymore in newer versions of the Jupyter and Python extensions for VS Code.

See 
[Inside of a notebook, magic cells should not cause an error in pylance
#17058](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17058) (in `microsoft/vscode-python`), which was fixed by the following two pull requests:

- [Fix diag messages for magics #17057](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/17057) (in `microsoft/vscode-python`)
- [Fix for magics and shell escapes #4](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter-lsp-middleware/pull/4) (in `microsoft/vscode-jupyter-lsp-middleware`)

All that confuses me now is why this problem happened to you, given that you asked this question on 2022-03-20, and those changes were made around 2021-08-20.

Note: It doesn't look like it from your screenshot, but in case you're actually using a cell script (.py file with `#%%` markers) and not a Jupyter notebook, then edit your user or workspace settings.json file to set `"jupyter.magicCommandsAsComments": true`, which allows you to use magic commands in comments (see [#3263](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/3263) and [#6494](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/6494)).

For your learning purposes / reference, I found this info by googling "`github vscode jupyter issues syntax error problem for ipython magic`" and looking through the top search results and linked GitHub issue tickets.